# set notation when showing that $X_n$ is a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

In Durrett's probability theory exercise 5.1.1,:

> Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. $\in \{ 1, 2, \dots, N\}$ and taking each value with probability $1/N$. Show that $X_n = |\{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n\}|$ is a Markov chain and compute its transition probability.

I don't understand what $X_n = |\{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n\}|$ is. Is it the sum of $\xi_i$'s or is it the cardinality of the set?

Comment: I think it is the cardinality of the set.  You can think of it as "the number of elements from $\{1, 2, \dots, N \}$ that some $\xi_i$ has landed on so far".  Similar to the coupon collector problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the cardinality of the set. In other words, $X_n$ counts the number of unique values among $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n$.

Comment: got it. thank you.